# How to pass a struct pointer variable as argument in order to edit it in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, arguments, argument-passing

C language

How can I send a struct pointer variable as argument to a function that is going to edit that struct variable?

I have the following struct in a separate header file:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int id;
    unsigned int value;
} type1;

typedef struct {
    unsigned int id;
    type1 children[32];
    unsigned int numChildren;
} person;
```

And I want to be able to do this:

```
void person_editID(person *p, unsigned int newID) {
    p->id = newID;
}
```

In this:

```
void function2() {
    person *p;
    person_editID(p,2);
    printf("Person ID: %d\n",p->id);
    person_editID(p,4);
    printf("Person ID: %d\n",p->id);
}
```

(The two functions are in separate files)

And have the result:

```
Person ID: 2
Person ID: 4
```

But with the code above there is an error:

> SIGSEGV... bad addr 0x0 (dataseg); err 0x6 nopage write ...

Is it because function2 p is not initialized? If so, how can I initialize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
person *p;
```

To this:

```
person p;
```

And this:

```
person_editID(p,2);
```

To this:

```
person_editID(&p,2);
```

Comment: @Edu: No, it would be equally incorrect in C++ too - an initialised pointer is an initialised pointer in either language.  In C++ you do have the option to use a `person&` type instead, but that alone would not make your code correct.

Comment: @Edu: You're confusing a pointer to the actual struct. you declared a `NULL` pointer ( a pointer that isn't pointing to anything (yet)) with this code `person *p;` <= it's not initialized so it doesn't point to anything, by removing the asterisk, you're declaring a struct itself, and by passing it like so `&p` you're not _passing the struct_, but passing the address of the struct to the function, effectively passing a pointer

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem:  It's worse that that, it was an uninitialised pointer rather than a NULL pointer.

Comment: @Clifford: Indeed so, to the OP: If you're not initializing a pointer to _Actually_ point at a memory address, please initialize it to `NULL`, to avoid possible `free` bugs. Initializing a pointer to `NULL` may feel silly, but at least it's safe. Think of it as a Hi-vis jacket

Comment: Thank you for the explanation everyone. It makes sense. I was creating a pointer to nowhere and that is why the error occurred (And maybe that's why it prints "0x0", no address).
My doubt was in how I could send the address. I create the struct and pass the address with &.
Once again thank you for the good and quick help. :)

Comment: @Edu: `0x0` is the null pointer. Technically it points to somewhere (the first byte of your virtual memory), but since a pointer of `0x0` is almost always an error or mistake, the OS sets it up so that accessing `0x0` is an error.